# Ada Calendar Arithmetic Difference 0 day between March 27 and March 28 2011

Tags: ada

Why do I have the value 0 days between March 27, 2011 and March 28, 2011?

```
with Ada.Calendar;            use Ada.Calendar;
with Ada.Calendar.Arithmetic; use Ada.Calendar.Arithmetic;
with Ada.Text_IO;             use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure main is
   t0 : Time      := Time_Of (Year => 2_011, Month => 3, Day => 27);
   t1 : Time      := Time_Of (Year => 2_011, Month => 3, Day => 28);
   da : Day_Count := t1 - t0;
begin
   Put_Line (da'Img);
end main;
```

```
[...]\obj\main.exe
 0
```

I wanted to get 1 day...

Comment: what compiler do you use? OS?
I've got `1`:
https://godbolt.org/z/6KfYnxzPM

Comment: gnat-x86_64-windows64-13.2.0-1

Comment: I got 1 with GNATMAKE Community 2021 (20210519-103) under Windows 10 on x64-based PC

Comment: The RM mentions that subtraction of two time types into a day_count operates the same as if you called the Difference operation from that same package.  The description of the Difference operation does have a special case for Day_Count being 0.  Maybe your implementation is hitting that?  you might try calling Difference instead and see what Seconds and Leap_Seconds return to see if that is it...as a debugging step.

Comment: @Jere 

 declare

      d:day_count;

      s:duration;

      l:Leap_Seconds_Count;

      begin 

         ada.calendar.arithmetic.Difference(Left => t1 , Right => t0 , Days =>d  , Seconds =>s  , Leap_Seconds => l );

         put_line(d'img);

         put_line(s'img);

        put_line(l'img);

     end;

Result:
 0

 82800.000000000

 0

Comment: It seems to me that this would have a link with local time because my local time is UTC+1 and therefore in the "Time_Of" function but I don't yet know where exactly.

Comment: If your time zone is CET, then summer time began 2011-03-27 02:00. This is why your seconds difference is /= 0. Day_Count counts 1 for each complete day (24 hours), and you have zero of them. If you want to ignore such time-zone effects, you need to convert to UTC.

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter  summer time ! Thanks !